# Setting Colors on the Header

Tags: html, css, header, background-color

```css
*
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #23272A;
}

.header
{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  border-bottom: 5px #FF9F00 solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#logo img
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 187.5px;
  height: 63.75px;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
}

.navbar
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

li
{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 22.5px 0 22.5px;
}

.navbar,
li,
a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar,
li,
a:hover
{
  color: #FF9F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#forumpoints,
#dsh
{
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#dosh
{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="author" content="Arszilla">

    <title>Website</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="header">

      <div id="logo">

        <img src="./img/logo.png"></img>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="leftnavbar">

          <ul>

            <li><span id="forumpoints">Forum Points:</span> <span id="dosh">1.00000000</span> <span id="dsh">Dosh</span></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="rightnavbar">

          <ul>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 1</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 2</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 3</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 4</a></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

I want to make the header have the color of #2C2F33, that will be lighter than the all body color (*) But instead I get results like the pic below

[image: Button1 Image]

I am not sure how to do this as if I insert `background-color: #2C2F33;` to `.navbar, li, a` there are some gaps like this

[image: Button 1 Image 2]

How can I fix this as I am not that experienced in HTML/CSS and require assistance for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason, why your navbars have darker background than the header, is because you gave this dark background to every element (that's what the `*` selector does). Now because navbars are children of header, they are drawn above the header and having their own background color already set, we cant see the color that header has.

Try giving the darker background only to the body like that:

```
* {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background-color: #23272A;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works just well!

Can I ask: I want the Forum Points to have a box, the color of #23272A

How can I do that? 

So the box just makes the inside of Forum Points that dark gray and outside remains to be #2C2F33

Comment: Cool! I'm glad I could help. To have darker background colour for the Forum Points, just add:`#leftnavbar { background: #23272A; }` to your style. Alternatively you could sdo this for the ul element inside with `#leftnavbar ul` or by assigning custom id for the ul element itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can give `background-color: #2C2F33` to `header *`, something like this:

```css
*
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #23272A;
}

.header
{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  border-bottom: 5px #FF9F00 solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#logo img
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 187.5px;
  height: 63.75px;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
}
.header *{
    background-color: #2C2F33;
 }
.navbar
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

li
{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 22.5px 0 22.5px;
}

.navbar,
li,
a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar,
li,
a:hover
{
  color: #FF9F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#forumpoints,
#dsh
{
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#dosh
{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="author" content="Arszilla">

    <title>Website</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="header">

      <div id="logo">

        <img src="./img/logo.png"></img>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="leftnavbar">

          <ul>

            <li><span id="forumpoints">Forum Points:</span> <span id="dosh">1.00000000</span> <span id="dsh">Dosh</span></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="rightnavbar">

          <ul>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 1</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 2</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 3</a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html">Button 4</a></li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give

```
.header * {
  background: #2C2F33;
}
```

Or you could wrap the main body color around another div after the header.

```
<div class="main">
   the rest of your stuff
</div>
```

And then do

```
*
{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

With

```
.main {
  background-color: #23272A;
}
```

That would be "better" css.